# Finding integral of logistic variable

Tags: calculus, probability

Suppose $f(x|a) = \frac{ae^{-ax}}{(1+e^{-ax})^{2}} a >0$.  How do you find the cdf of this function? Would you have to evaluate $\int_{0}^{x}f(x|a)dx$. What would be an easy way to do this. I try $u$ where $u=-ax$ subsitution and I cannot get the solution. Are other techniques required?

Answer (score 1):

The lower bound of the integral is $-\infty$ in order for the PDF to be normalized.  Then the CDF is

$$F(x) = a \int_{-\infty}^x dt \:\frac{e^{-a t}}{(1+e^{-a t})^2}$$

Substitute $u=e^{-a t}$ in the integral to get

$$F(x) = \int_{e^{-a x}}^{\infty} \frac{du}{(1+u)^2} = \frac{1}{1+e^{-a x}}$$

Comment: Is the last line just an identity? How did you get that equality?

Comment: From $$\int \frac{du}{(1+u)^2} = -\frac{1}{1+u}$$

Comment: Since $du = ae^{-ax} $ isn't the integral multiplied by -1?

Comment: @phil12: it would, but notice that I reversed the upper and lower integration limits.

Comment: So reversing the limits changes the sign of the integral?

Comment: @phil12: yes.  Think of the fundamental theorem of integral calc.